# How to calculate the average hours between two different times in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Let's say, I have the following times.

```
Time_1      Time_2          
10:08:00    10:08:00          
11:00:00    12:00:00         
12:30:00    14:30:00
```

I would like to calculate the average time between them and would like to get the following result.

```
Time_1      Time_2         Average_time
10:08:00    10:08:00         10:08:00
11:00:00    12:00:00         11.30.00
12:30:00    14:30:00         13.15.00
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You should try converting them into simpler datatypes like maybe a number representing the number of seconds passed since midnight. That way you can average the two dates with simple number addition divided by 2, then convert that resulting average into a date format.

Comment: Related:  [how-to-calculate-the-time-interval-between-two-time-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096953/how-to-calculate-the-time-interval-between-two-time-strings)

Comment: By the way, the average of 12:30:00 & 14:30:00 should be 13:30:00, not 13:15:00.

Answer (score 3):

you can use timedelta, this code calculate average of times.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
time1="11:00:00"
time2="12:00:00"
t1 = pd.Timedelta(time1)
t2 = pd.Timedelta(time2)
avg=(t1+t2)/2

d = {'time1':[t1] , 'time2':[t2], 'average':[avg]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df.to_string())
```

output:

```
    time1    time2  average
0 11:00:00 12:00:00 11:30:00
```

Comment: In your case works fine. How can you apply this in the dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

Python has a built-in function to calculate time, timedelta.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

t1 = '10:00:00'
t2 = '11:00:00' # For example
format = '%H:%M:%S'

startTime = datetime.strptime(t1, format) # convert t1 to time object
tdelta = datetime.strptime(t2, format) - datetime.strptime(t1, format)
```

Now, tdelta contains the time difference between t1 & t2. timedelta.seconds will return the time in seconds. Just add half of the seconds with the starting time.

```
tdelta = startTime + timedelta(0, tdelta.seconds//2)

print(tdelta.time()) # Your expected output
```

Comment: How can you apply your solution to the data frame? I am getting an error ```ValueError: Value must be Timedelta, string, integer, float, timedelta or convertible, not Series```

Comment: Read the official documentation. It describes how can you convert dataframe to string objects.  
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
df['Average_time'] = (df['Time_1']-df['Time_2'])/2+df['Time_1']
```

Answer (score 1):

an alternative:

```
class TimeObject:

    def __init__(self, s=None):
        if s:
            hours, minutes, seconds = [int(v) for v in s.split(":")]
            self.seconds = hours*3600 + minutes*60 + seconds
        else:
            self.seconds = 0

    def __str__(self):
        hours = self.seconds//3600
        minutes = (self.seconds - hours*3600)//60
        seconds = (self.seconds-hours*3600-minutes*60)
        return f"{hours:02d}:{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}"

    @classmethod
    def fromSeconds(cls, seconds):
        ans = TimeObject()
        ans.seconds = seconds
        return ans


def average(a, b):
    avg = (a.seconds+b.seconds)//2
    return TimeObject.fromSeconds(avg)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    o1 = TimeObject("12:30:00")
    o2 = TimeObject("14:30:00")

    ans = average(o1, o2)
    print(ans)
```

But I think you should prefer the timedelta solution

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['Average_time']=(df[['Time_1','Time_2']]
                    .astype(str)
                    .agg(pd.to_timedelta)
                    .eval("Time_1+Time_2").div(2))
```

output:

```
    Time_1      Time_2      Average_time
0   10:08:00    10:08:00    0 days 10:08:00
1   11:00:00    12:00:00    0 days 11:30:00
2   12:30:00    14:30:00    0 days 13:30:00
```

If you really don't care about **days** in timedelta and you want only hours then you can use:

```
df['Average_time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Average_time'].dt.total_seconds(),unit='s').dt.time
```

output of `df`:

```
    Time_1      Time_2      Average_time
0   10:08:00    10:08:00    10:08:00
1   11:00:00    12:00:00    11:30:00
2   12:30:00    14:30:00    13:30:00
```

If you want to include **days** as well in time delta and convert them to hours then you can follow up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62103547/how-to-convert-timedelta-to-hours/62104149#62104149)

Answer (score 0):

With `datetime` objects, you could convert its to [timestamp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) which is a float representation of a date, compute the mean, and convert back to `datetime` object.

```py
>>> d1 = dateutil.parser.parse("1970-01-01T11:00:00")
>>> d2 = dateutil.parser.parse("1970-01-01T12:00:00")
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp((d1.timestamp() + d2.timestamp()) / 2)
datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 11, 30)
```

But in your case you only have time part of datetime, which can be confuse. What's the mean of "23:59:00" and "00:01:00" ?

Maybe you should complete time with arbitrary day, assuming that if t1 > t2 then t2 is day+1.